# Mask an existing input value with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I created a function to get the length of my input value and applying a different replace (a mask) for each one, but it's not working. Check it out:

```
function mask_vat(inputID) {
    var mystr = document.getElementById(inputID).value;
    var str_length = mystr.length;
    var pattern, replacement;
        switch(str_length) {
            case 14:
                pattern = '/^(\d{3}).\d{3}.\d{3}-(\d{2})$/';
                replacement = '$1.XXX.XXX-$2';
                break;
            case 18:
                pattern = '/.\d{3}.\d{3}\//';
                replacement = '.xxx.xxx/';
                break;
        }
    mystr.replace(pattern, replacement);
}
```

what's wrong in the function??

Comment: A nice website to test regular expression is this one : https://regex101.com/#javascript

Answer (score 1):

In Regex `.` represents all character except new line. To use a `.` use `\.`.